# Minikube change address of ingress addon

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

When I deploy ingress using ingress addon (`minikube addons enable ingress`) it address sets to `192.168.49.2`:

```
NAME           CLASS    HOSTS             ADDRESS        PORTS     AGE
some-ingress   <none>   application.com   192.168.49.2   80, 443   86s
```

How do I change it to 127.0.0.1 (or external ip) to be able to receive requests from outside?

UPD:
Using `vm_driver=docker`; `minikube ip` returns `192.168.49.2`.

UPD2: Ingress config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: application-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - application.com
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: application.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/"
            backend:
              service:
                name: application-back
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Comment: Could you share your Ingress config? Are you following any guide in order to set it up?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I attached Ingress config to the post. Following this guide: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't have to change it in order to receive external requests.

The `rules:` part of your configuration:

```
spec:
  rules:
    - host: application.com
```

expects a DNS record with `application.com` name. Later in the guide you can see:

> Add the following line to the bottom of the `/etc/hosts` file.
>
> Note: If you are running Minikube locally, use `minikube ip` to get the
> external IP. The IP address displayed within the ingress list will be
> the internal IP.
>
> `172.17.0.15 hello-world.info`
>
> This sends requests from `hello-world.info` to Minikube.

That entry points to your ingress IP or Minikube IP. Of course you need to adjust your IP and DNS name.

If you would like to curl the IP instead of DNS name you can do so by removing the host rule from your ingress. For example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: application-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
     paths:
     - path: "/"
       backend:
         serviceName: application-back
         servicePort: 80
```

After that you should be able to `curl -Lk` by IP with no issues.